# WooCommerce Add To Cart URL adding multiple items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using WooCommerce add to cart URLs to build a direct checkout widget on a client's homepage.  I thought I had everything working well, but for some reason when they click the direct checkout links, it adds three products to their cart instead of one. I disabled all plugins except for WooCommerce and the site-specific plugin which generates the widget.  The same issue happens when you simply enter the link manually into the address bar.

The development site is [rlmarts.staging.wpengine.com](http://rlmarts.staging.wpengine.com)

Any insight into why this might be occuring?

Comment: I tried redirecting to a different page instead, and now it only adds two instead of three, but that's still one too many...

Comment: your site url not working please correct url.

Comment: Apologies. Fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution I stumbled on that's working for now.  I started using the page-id querystring URL format, like http://rlmarts.staging.wpengine.com/?page-id=19&add-to-cart=8533&quantity=2 instead of http://rlmarts.staging.wpengine.com/checkout?add-to-cart=8533&quantity=2.

The overall site permalink structure is still by post name.

Comment: This didn't work for me. Still adding 3 products even if quantity is set to "1".

Comment: Okay. I found the issue. The reason for the third product addition, was because I was refreshing the URL with appended parameters. (Doh!) This can and should be resolved with a few lines of PHP to strip off the appended parameters. That laves me down to 2. A redirect was causing the addition of 2 products. I had for some reason been using a custom permanent URL rewrite structure. It was fixed after changing it to "Post name". Any redirect could cause WooCommerce to add more than one product. Check your .htaccess if you have additional redirects.